# Custom field for grants- type is contact reference, not working in profile when batch updating

Tags: profile, civigrant, contact-reference

We have a site on 5.8 D7

With a function to batch update contact reference fields in grants

The field works fine when editting a grant record, but shows the message "loading failed" when updating via profile. This is a function the site has had for at east two years, and was working prior to the 5.8 upgrade.

[image: Screenshot of contact ref field not loading]

Cannot recreate on sandbox- can't add grant fields to a profile

Anyone seen something similar?

Comment: not quite following. why can't you replicate on sandbox? do you have some custom stuff on your site?

Comment: Created the new custom data field fine.

Went to create a new profile, and grant fields weren't presented as an option to select fields from

Comment: did you check if Contact Reference fields work for any entity via Batch Update by Profile - i just tried on Individuals on dmaster and nothing happened at all in the contact reference field

Comment: Not on dmaster. (Just seen your cref profile)

Did create something similar on local site this afternoon. But then phone calls happened. And I got pulled on to something else.

Contact reference fields work ok on the contact record, and profiles behave as expected in preview. Look to be not working in batch update mode.

Comment: Ok. Glad it's not just me.

Will raise in the issues queue tomorrow.